# integerNode in Symfony's Config component seems to apply validation before env vars processors are executed

Tags: symfony, environment-variables

I am working in Symfony 5.4. It looks like when I try to typecast my env variable to int it's always 0.
The docs: https://symfony.com/doc/5.x/configuration/env_var_processors.html

This is in the .env

```
TWO_FACTOR_TRUSTED_COOKIE_LIFETIME=3600
```

This is in the scheb_2fa.yaml:

```
scheb_two_factor:
    trusted_device:
        lifetime: '%env(int:TWO_FACTOR_TRUSTED_COOKIE_LIFETIME)%'
```

This is the error:

```
The value 0 is too small for path "scheb_two_factor.trusted_device.lifetime".
Should be greater than or equal to 1
```

If I leave the type casting out I get another error

```
# This: '%env(TWO_FACTOR_TRUSTED_COOKIE_LIFETIME)%' produces ->

Invalid type for path "scheb_two_factor.trusted_device.lifetime".
Expected "int", but got "string".
```

I updated all my .env files to the same value "3600" to be sure,
The output of 
`bin/console debug:dotenv | grep -iE '(Variable|TWO_FACTOR)'`:

[image]

It must have something to do with this in the vendor folder:
https://github.com/scheb/2fa-bundle/blob/6e51477c53070f27ac3e3d36be1a991870db415a/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php#L109
-> line 109

```
->integerNode('lifetime')->defaultValue(60 * 24 * 3600)->min(1)->end()
```

Ìf I change it to "0" the error is gone:

```
->min(0)
```

And in the end I have the correct value from the env in my final container. So somehow this "min(1)" check is too early. I guess this gets checked before the Env processor kicks in and thinks the value is 0.

---

**To reproduce**

You can easily reproduce it in the base symfony session config file:

```
# /vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

// before
->scalarNode('cookie_lifetime')->end()

// after
->integerNode('cookie_lifetime')->min(1)->end()
```

And with this env

```
GENERAL_COOKIE_LIFETIME=3600
```

And this in the framework config:

```
framework:
    session:
        cookie_lifetime: '%env(int:GENERAL_COOKIE_LIFETIME)%'
```

Then `cache:clear` and you will have the same error

Comment: I updated my answer, if I don't typecast it says the string type is wrong

Comment: It says `TWO_FACTOR_TRUSTED_COOKIE_LIFETIME 3600 n/a 3600 n/a`

Comment: @DylanKAS if that were the case, it _should_ be visible on the output of `debug:dotenv`.

Comment: Updated question. When I change this ->min(1) in the vendor `->integerNode('lifetime')->defaultValue(60 * 24 * 3600)->min(1)->end()
` to `->integerNode('lifetime')->defaultValue(60 * 24 * 3600)->min(0)->end()
` The error is gone. So somehow this "min(1)" is too early or something like that

Comment: Sorry, wrong version in link, I actually use Scheb v6.12.0 and Symfony 5.4.34

Comment: FWIW, just tried with Sf 5, 6 and 7, and got the same results.

Comment: Hmmm. Weird tht it hasn't been caught until now. The problem seems to stem from `Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ValidateEnvPlaceholdersPass`. Here it attempts to validate the configuration file with "fake" data to account for the not yet processed environment variable values. But it creates very simple fixtures, that could fail a number of configuration constraints. For example, it "assumes" a value of `0` for an int placeholder, or an empty string for `string`. I can imagine either of those failing in a fair number of situations.

Comment: Searching for [related issues](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues?q=is%3Aissue+ValidateEnvPlaceholdersPass) might give you a hint.